# "How to add 'A delete option in an audio tag player' in PHP "

Tags: php, html

"I have fetch the uploaded file name and is being played in my browser. How can i add a delete function to each user uploaded song?"

```
echo "<hr />";
echo "<h4>".$name."<br /><a href='#' title='Uploaded time'><i 
    class='fa fa-clock'>".$uploaded_time."</i></a></h4>";
echo "<audio controls src='$location'>
Your browser does not support the audio element</audio>";
```

Comment: See PHP's [unlink](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my question. Replaced the codes with this;

```
echo "<h4>".$name."</h4>";
echo "<h4><a href='?del=".$name." '><i class='fa fa-trash' title='Delete song now'>Click to Delete</i></a> <a href='' title='Uploaded time'><i class='fa fa-clock'>".$uploaded_time."</i></a></h4>";
echo "<audio controls src= '$location'  preload='metadata'> 
Your browser does not support the audio player</audio>";
```

After changing the audio player codes, the delete action should be in this format;

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$dbname = "scuploads";

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);

if(isset($_GET['del']))
    $name = $_GET['del'];
    {
$sql= "DELETE from songs WHERE name = '$name'" or die("error in query");
$deletesong = $con->query($sql) or die("error in query");
    }
?>
```

this lines of codes will do the simple magic of deleting html 5 audio player in php